# Swift - Images Distortion in universal app

Tags: ios, ipad

I have created iPhone app with a lot of images as interface details. After completion, i decided that i also want to support iPad. So in size classes i chosen REG REG and edited constraints for new device.

Now I have a problem. All images in iPad mode are distorted. Absolutely all. I test on iPad 2 and physical iPad mini. For example I have a png with text

here it is on iPhone 6+ [image]

here of iPad2
[image]

as you see on iPhone it is smooth, but on iPad pixellizated.

And that happens to all images

Why can this happen ?

Comment: Are you testing on a physical device, or just the Simulator?

Comment: both - simulator and device

Comment: You might want to take a peek at the resolution of the image you're attempting to display on the iPad 2. http://www.iosres.com

Answer (score 1):

As the resolution of both, iPad and iPhone differ from each other, and you are comparing an image of iPhone6+ with iPad, so iPhone6+ will take @3x image while your iPad mini and iPad 2 will take the images of size @2x(if they are retina). So to support the image for iPad you have to add the images for iPad in your `images.xcassets` folder if your are using the xcassets like this

[image]

To get the options for images you have to select your xcassets folder then from the attribute inspector you have to check iPad.

Comment: Didn't help. I tried to provide 1x, 2x and even 3x instead of 1x. Quality is still poor

Comment: You have to replace 2x image with 3x image then you will see the difference.